# Error - cannot infer type-variable(s) K,V - OpenJDK 1.8 vs ECJ 1.8 difference with lambdas?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, ecj

I have following code:

```
Type a;
List<Pair<Consumer<LocalDate>, LocalDate>> list = new LinkedList<>();
a.getListB().stream().forEach((TypeB b) -> { 
   list.add(new Pair<>(b::setDate, b.getDate()));
  });
```

And eclipse allows reduction to (no error):

```
Type a;
List<Pair<Consumer<LocalDate>, LocalDate>> list = new LinkedList<>();
a.getListB().stream().forEach(b -> list.add(new Pair<>(b::setDate, b.getDate())));
```

But openJdk build fails on

```
[ERROR]     reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) K,V
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object is not a functional interface)
```

Project compliance is set to 1.8

versions:
Openjdk 1.8.0-191
Eclipse 4.10

Is it ECJ bug?

Comment: Eclipse 4.10 is 7 releases behind and Java 8 update 191 is also pretty old. Please do not waste time using outdated software.

Comment: Do not use ```forEach``` for building up a list. Use ```.collect(toList())``` instead.